# regular expression in css fails

Tags: css, regex

I am creating a user css via stylish on Firefox 46.0.1 on OS X 10.10.5.  I created the following style rule.  I'm looking to match on one or more numbers as part of the regular expression below.  When I use
.* my regular expression works.  Tried the * since + wasn't working. 
None of these three expressions in my regular expression work.

- \d*
- [0-9]*
- [0-9]+

My page is:
  https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7522221?decorator=print&displayFullThread=true

```
/* this regular expression finds the page, when used alone. */
/*
@-moz-document 
  regexp("https:\/\/discussions\.apple\.com\/thread\/.*\?decorator=print&displayFullThread=true.*") 
{  
   html, body, h1, li {background-color: chartreuse !important;   
    border: 6px solid grey !important;}  

}
*/ 


/* This regular expression does not work when used alone */
@-moz-document 
    regexp("https:\/\/discussions\.apple\.com\/thread\/\d*\?decorator=print&displayFullThread=true.*") 
    {  
       html, body, h1, li {background-color: chartreuse !important;   
        border: 6px solid grey !important;}  

    }
```

Comment: You'll most likely need to escape `\d` as `\\d` when specifying it as a string.

Comment: Use `regexp("https://discussions\\.apple\\.com/thread/\\d*\\?decorator=print&displayFullThread=true.*")`

Answer (score 0):

You have to use two backslashes in this situation, one to escape the backslash itself in the string in your code and another for the regular expression itself. The string you should use is this:

```
"https://discussions\\.apple\\.com/thread/\\d*\\?decorator=print&displayFullThread=true.*"
```

By using the above in your code, you get the following regular expression:

```
"https://discussions\.apple\.com/thread/\d*\?decorator=print&displayFullThread=true.*"
```

Also, note that you don't have to escape forward slashes.

Read about [The Backslash Plague](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html#the-backslash-plague) (although this is a Python reference, it should provide general information about the topic)